# How to find values from position 100 on notepad++

Tags: regex, search, notepad++

I want to extract characters/values on position 100-105 within each line for the whole document in Notepad++ by using regular expressions.

How can I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Do a Search (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>)
2. Select `Regular expressions` and be sure to have `. matches new line` unchecked
3. Enter following pattern in search box: `(?<=^.{99})(.{6})`

Explanations:

- `(?<=...)` corresponds to a pattern before what we are looking for
- `^.{99}` corresponds to the first 99 characters of the line
- `(.{6})` corresponds to 6 characters (from 100 to 105)

You can comment if this is not clear enough.

Comment: Thank you Jean-Francois , the expression works flawlessly. Is there a chance to tweak this command by adding the line #. I mean I want to find characters from position 100-105 on row/line 100 ?

Comment: Hi Sam. The only way to do that is to go to line #100 (e.g. Ctrl+G), select the line and then run the regular expression on selected text... For your purpose, I suggest using some script like Perl (which is perfect for text parsing). Meanwhile, can you accept my answer for your problem?